# Writing an interface for networking in an embedded system

Tags: c, networking, embedded

I'm writing a driver in C for a WiFi module attached to a PIC18 microcontroller. I want to implement some functions that I'm familiar with in computer application level programming like Window's API [recv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for WinSock.
The module itself already implements the WiFi communication protocol and the TCP/IP stack, and communicate with the PIC18 microcontroller through UART.

Is this the correct way to achieve this? Efficiency is very important here (It's an embedded system too).

```
#define RECEIVE_TIMEOUT 200
#define RECEIVE_RETRY_COUNT 4

UINT16 ReceiveData(void* _data, UINT16 length)
{
    UINT16 received = 0;
    UINT8 retry_count = 0;

    while(received < length)
    {
        if(UART1_Data_Ready())
        {
            ((BYTE*)_data)[received] = ReceiveByte();
            received++;
            continue;
        }

        if(retry_count == RECEIVE_RETRY_COUNT)
            break;

        retry_count++;
        Delay_ms(RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/RECEIVE_RETRY_COUNT);
    }

    return received;
}
```

Comment: Could you give further details about `ReceiveByte()`?

Comment: @no1 The ReceiveByte() part is just a simple UART read. `UART1_Read()`. I don't know the specific of this function because it's from a library.

Comment: How is `Delay_ms` implemented? nop loop, or asynchronous?

Comment: @rolfl `Delay_ms()` Is implemented as loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a small note on sleeping when waiting for input.  As others have said
your loop is inefficient in that it uses a simple busy loop.  This has at
least two potential problems:

1. it prevent other activities from executing;
2. it uses power.

But these are not necessarily problems for **your** application.  And if in
your application there really is nothing else to be done until bytes arrive
and if power consumption is not a problem, then a busy loop is by far the
simplest solution.

Using interrupts will inevitably complicate the rest of your code and should
be avoided **unless really necessary** (for example if there are other
computing tasks that need to run while waiting for input).

If 1 above is not important but 2 is (ie if you need to minimise power use)
you could put the core to sleep during waiting and have the byte-receive wake
it.  This would retain the benefit of avoiding interrupt handling. You would
need to set a timer to wake the core too if you need a timeout.

On the details of your code, I dislike the use of Windows types in an embedded
system.  What is wrong with `int` and `char` or their unsigned varieties?

Your leading underscore on `_data` is reserved by something or other and is anyway
pointless.

I don't object to passing in a `void *` (after all, C stdlib functions `recv`
and `read` do this), but I would assign it to a local variable of appropriate
type and avoid casts.  This makes absolutely no difference when the buffer is
used just once, as here and is just a personal preference.

And using `continue` is usually frowned on and often unnecessary.

```
int ReceiveData(void *data, int length)
{
    unsigned char *p = data;
    int received = 0;
    int retry = 0;

    while (received < length)
    {
        if (UART1_Data_Ready())
        {
            p[received++] = ReceiveByte();
        }
        else if (++retry <= RECEIVE_RETRY_COUNT)
        {
            Delay_ms(RECEIVE_TIMEOUT/RECEIVE_RETRY_COUNT);
        }
        else break;
    }
    return received;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is running synchronously (the `Delay_ms` is a spin loop). As a result, no other code can be running when you are waiting.

Ideally, you should be using an interrupt handler (`PIR1.RCIF`) to wait on the message, and when the USART indicates there is data available, you can append it to a message buffer, and signal the main-loop code when the data buffer is complete.

Consider reading up on some code examples [( **Link to zip file** )](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/usart.zip), and [the USART data sheet (pdf)](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/31018a.pdf) for details on the interrupt handler.

Using an interrupt would be a much better solution.

On the other hand, your code is not spinning on the USART very efficiently anyway.

You are waiting a full `Delay_ms` loop when the data may be available much sooner.

Consider spinning the following way:

```
#define RECEIVE_TIMEOUT 200
#define RECEIVE_RETRY_COUNT 4

UINT16 ReceiveData(void* _data, UINT16 length)
{
    UINT16 received = 0;
    UINT8 retry_count = 0;
    UINT16 timeout = 0;

    while(received < length)
    {
        timeout = TIMER1TICK; // pick a timer that cycles.... in your system
        timeout += TIMEALLOWED; // add the allowed timeout to the current time.
        while(TIMER1TICK != timeout && !UART1_Data_Ready())
        {
            // spin until data comes available on the USART

        }

        if(!UART1_Data_Ready())
            break; // timeout ....

        ((BYTE*)_data)[received] = ReceiveByte();
        received++;

    }

    return received;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I see wrong with the algorithm is that if you don't have any data coming in from the WiFi module, you could potentially sit and wait for 200ms (the value of `RECEIVE_TIMEOUT`) before returning to the caller to say "no data". Is there other work that your main program could be doing during that time? If so, it might be worthwhile to split the check for incoming data and the reading of that data into separate functions.

---

- When setting up constants that measure physical quantities, I like to attach the units of measurement to the symbolic name. That way, it becomes obvious if you pass a millisecond quantity into a function that expects seconds or microseconds (or kilograms or... you get the idea).

  ```
  #define RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_ms 200
  [... code elided ...]

    Delay_ms(RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_ms/RECEIVE_RETRY_COUNT);
  ```
- The first parameter to the function is declared as `void *`, but its only use is as a `BYTE *`:

  ```
  UINT16 ReceiveData(void* _data, UINT16 length)
  {
      [... code elided ...]
      ((BYTE*)_data)[received] = ReceiveByte();
      [... code elided ...]
  }
  ```

  This is a strong hint that it should be declared as a `BYTE *` in the first place.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I though could happen in this code, but I don't know what is the best solution to fix that. Any ideas? As for the other things you mentioned, for the defines there is a comment above them which explains what are they doing and what physical quantities they are using, but if you say it's not enough i'll take your advice :). As for the parameter type, I have a question: Where should I really use `void*` as parameter? (Except function pointer and parameterless function)

Comment: Look into using the UART's "data ready" interrupt for detecting incoming data, and potentially using a Timer/Counter for the delay function as well. The explanatory comments on the #defines are great, but in the code, the definition can be far away from the point of use, so I think the extra information in the macro name is helpful. IMO, `void *` is only useful where you truly don't know or care about the type of something, e.g. malloc(), memset(), etc., or if you're defining a standard API that takes an unspecified user-defined type that they take responsibility for.

Answer (score 3):

One more thing missed in other comments. The `UART` is capable of detecting errors. They do happen, and must be reported upstairs. You must read and analyze `RCSTA` before reading `RCREG`